# 502 Bad Gateway: net/http GET failed with IPSec Tunnel

Tags: go

When making remote `GET` requests with `net/http` package through `IPSec Tunnel(VPN)` on windows, `GET` request failed with response code `502 Bad Gateway`. However request with same `headers`, `uri`, `method` sent by `curl` works greatly. The `go` source code looks like:

```golang
    var req *http.Request
    req, err = http.NewRequest('GET', *uri, reader)
    if nil != err {
        level.Warn(log).Log("msg", "Unable to create request", "err", err, "uri", uri)
        return nil, err
    }
    if nil != req.Body {
        defer req.Body.Close()
    }
    for h, v := range opts.Headers {
        req.Header.Add(h, *v)
    }

    client := http.Client{}
    if nil != err {
        return nil, err
    }
    res, err := client.Do(req)
    if nil != err {
        level.Warn(log).Log("msg", "Unable to send request", "err", err, "uri", uri)
        return nil, err
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()

    buf, err := io.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if nil != err {
        level.Warn(log).Log("msg", "Unable to read response", "err", err, "uri", uri, "status", res.Status, "status_code", res.StatusCode)
        return nil, err
    }
```

After capturing and analysising the traffic, I found the request sent by `curl` can be captured normally on `VPN Interface` but `GET` request sent from `go(net/http)` lost.

Then I guess it probably because the framework seleted wrong interface to send the packet.

So I tried to find out proper local network interface and specify its `LocalAddr` to send my `GET` request as following:

```golang
func Client(u string) (*http.Client, error) {
    uri, err := url.Parse(u)
    if nil != err {
        return nil, err
    }
    host := uri.Host
    port := uri.Port()
    if Empty == port {
        if uri.Scheme == "http" {
            host = host + ":80"
        } else if uri.Scheme == "https" {
            host = host + ":443"
        }
    }
    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", host)
    if nil != err {
        return nil, err
    }
    addr := conn.LocalAddr().(*net.TCPAddr)
    // **make sure using random port as local port**
    addr.Port = 0

    dialer := &net.Dialer{LocalAddr: addr}
    dialContext := func(ctx context.Context, network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
        conn, err := dialer.Dial(network, addr)
        return conn, err
    }

    transport := &http.Transport{DialContext: dialContext}
    client := &http.Client{
        Transport: transport,
    }
    return client, nil
}
```

And after repacing `client` with `Client` function, `GET` request final works.

`client := &http.Client{}` => `client, err := Client(uri)`

**Then my question is why `golang` doesn't select proper local network interface to send request automatically?**

Comment: Do all IPv4 and IPv6 addresses for the hostname have a route through the IPSec tunnel?

Comment: Yes. Cause my `curl` can works absolutely fine.

Comment: *"Cause my curl can works absolutely fine"* - if this is your only reasoning then it is not sufficient. It might be that different programs use different IP addresses if multiple are configured for the same hostname. For example some applications prefer IPv4 while others prefer IPv6.

Comment: Actually, there is no DHCP or static IPv6 addresses has been assigned to any network interfacecs on my laptop yet. I partially agree your idea and I'm curious what's acctually makes this different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging the `net.dial#DialContext`, I found the address has been changed to my proxy address in `Visual Studio Code` settings. And my proxy server won't be able to handle my application requests.

[image]

[image]

When I removed the proxy setting, `net.dial` works as expected.

#### What matters

I'm using vscode to work with `TypeScript/Java/Golang...` and this is the first time I encounter a proxy issue on `Developing Application` in `vscode` IDE. In other words, I never thought the `IDE` proxy will work on the work it builds. Since extensions or IDE itself use this proxy settings is reasonable but my `golang` project debugging use it too that really confused me a lot.